# Microphone stops working on Chrome when using GoToMeeting

Tags: google-chrome, pulseaudio, microphone

I have several microphones: the default built in plus the one from a monitor an a wireless Jabra. I sometimes also plug a camera with built-in microphone

They all work fine and I can switch from one to another at any point, any application

Since beginning this month, all microphones stop working shortly after I initiate a GoToMeeting session - on Chrome. But they only stop working on Chrome - any tab. I can use any other application and they work just fine, all microphones

As soon as I restart Chrome, all microphones work again on any Chrome tab, including GoToMeeting ... after a while and then the cycle restarts

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and last version of Chrome (at time of posting):  79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I am posting here because I cannot find any similar issue anywhere and GoToMeeting Support has not been particularly helpful on this item (not strong Linux supporters, they are)

I tried disabling and re enabling pulsaudio and played with pavucontrol but no difference. The relevant information is that everything works fine outside Chrome

Comment: I have the same problem under Ubuntu 16.04 and Google Chrome 79.0.3945.117. Microphone works for couple minutes then it drops for now apparent reason. Have to restart browser and log into meeting again.

Comment: and yes, I found also this: https://community.logmein.com/t5/GoToMeeting-Discussions/GoToMeeting-kills-my-microphone-on-Chrome/m-p/214957#M26526 - so it seems, that it's a chrome bug, and using Chrome Beta should solve it. ( https://www.google.com/intl/de/chrome/beta/ )